# What's the current App Store Review turnaround time?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Have heard of developers waiting 2 to 6 weeks in 2009. When they reject the app, you resubmit and wait another 2 to 6 weeks. So finally the review takes a few months. Same for fixing bugs. Does this rule still apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS Dev Center [News](http://developer.apple.com/news/) indicates that in the last week, 56% of new app submissions were reviewed and 71% of app updates.

Comment: That doesn't seem too clear to me.  Does this mean (based on current wait times) there's ~56% chance of a new app submission being approved within 7 days?

Comment: This information seems a bit outdated to me

Answer (score 4):

Someone created a neat website to answer this question based on information ios developers share on twitter:

http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/

However I've also heard there's various factors at play. Review times might be longer if it's a more complex app, or an app using certain features, or if it's your first app submitted with this developer account. The above site just shows the average time people report.

Comment: As a random data-point for today: that site reports an average of a 5 day wait. Just submitted my app, we'll see!!

Comment: Great resource thanks, looks like they've registered http://appreviewtimes.com since your OP.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this post in the 2020s, there's a new resource for this! Current average App Store review times (plus TestFlight beta review times and build processing times), all backed by real world data and regularly updated:

[runway.team/appreviewtimes](https://runway.team/appreviewtimes)